# mysql loading previous query data to present queries also

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/cluster", "root",
                    "password");
            PreparedStatement pst = con
                    .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_DETAILS (EMPLOYEE_ID,NAME,SALARY,DEPARTMENT,MANAGER)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
            pst.clearParameters();
            pst.setObject(1, 101);
            pst.setObject(2, "sam");
            pst.setObject(3, 1000000);
            pst.setObject(4, "IT");
            pst.setObject(5, "jord");
            pst.execute();
            System.out.println("values got updted-----");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

for the first time this query is working fine and data is getting loaded into MySql data base.But when i execute the same programme after changing the values also the database is loading previously loaded values again and again..
                           why this is happening..

Comment: even without setting any objects to related placeholders if i run the programme it  is not showing any exception and db is loading a new record with previous values...

Comment: try closing resources you have opened

Comment: i think the proble is with eclipse itself ,not even declared variable con but  it is printing sysout(con); as com.mysql.jdbc.Connection@4bd767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it,the problem is actually with eclipse itself.After making any changes to the eclipse is not saving the new copy automatically and when we try to compile it is compiling the old copy without any new changes.If i manually save the code after any changes it is working fine...